# Can video core library send the live H264/AAC iOS Camera stream to Wowza using RTMP

Tags: ios, video-streaming, h.264, aac, videocore

Hi I am developing a app based an Broadcast for that i am using video core library i need to encode the video H.264 and audio AAC then only Wowza server stream my video but i don't know how implement that can any body help me out please

Answer (score 0):

Check out the sample project at video core it pretty much gives you step by step how to start a rtmp session.

```
 //Create a session and add preview to ur Viewcontrollers Subview
_session = [[VCSimpleSession alloc] initWithVideoSize:self.view.frame.size frameRate:30 bitrate:32000 useInterfaceOrientation:YES];
    _session.orientationLocked = YES;
[self.view addSubview:_session.previewView];
_session.previewView.frame = self.view.bounds;
_session.delegate = self;


  // then when ur ready start a session
[_session startRtmpSessionWithURL:@"rtmp://RTMPURL/APPPATH" andStreamKey:@"STREAM_KEY"];
```